# Match Pattern to ignore white space in source while match.find

Tags: java, regex, whitespace

I have a Pattern `String pageText="Hello World, How areyou doing"` (no space). and  have a search `pattern` representing `"How are you"`

```
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(pageText));
int count = 0;
while (matcher.find()) {
  count++;
}
```

`counter` is returning `0` as the space is missing in my `pageText` variable.

Is there a way to ignore the whitespace check and should be able to find the match for the pattern "How are you"?

Comment: Remove all spaces from subject and search strings before comparing. You can even avoid regex and use `String#contains`

Answer (score 0):

One of simplest ways could be replacing spaces with `\s*` in regex pattern so it would look more like `"How\\s*are\\s*you"` so it could match `Howareyou` `How areyou` `Howare you`.

```
String pageText="Hello World, How areyou doing";

Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("How are you".replaceAll("\\s+","\\\\s*"));

Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(pageText);
int count = 0;
while (matcher.find()) {
  count++;
}

System.out.println(count);
```

Edit:

Since you are using `Pattern.quote` to escape all regex special characters adding `\s*` inside doesn't make much sense since it will also be escaped. Simple solution for that would be quoting only words since only they can have regex metacharacters which require escaping, so we are lookinf for solution which will build us something like

```
quote(word1)\s*quote(word2)\s*quote(word3)
```

Code for that can look like:

```
String pageText = "Hello World, How areyou doing";
String searchFor = "How are you";

String searchingRegex = Stream.of(searchFor.split("\\s+"))//stream of words
        .map(word -> Pattern.quote(word))//quote each word
        .collect(Collectors.joining("\\s*"));//join words with `\s*` delimiter

Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(searchingRegex);
//...
```

Comment: Thanks shemo, it works in a one scenario, but I am not able to use this replaceall combined with pattern.quote("How are you".replaceAll("\\s+","\\\\s*"));                                                                    String pageText="Hello World, How areyou (Figure 6a) doing";
String searchPattern = "How are you (Figure 6a)";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(Pattern.quote(searchPattern.replaceAll("\\s+","\\\\s*")));
 Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(pageText);
 int count = 0;
 while (matcher.find()) {
   count++;
 } System.out.println("count:" + count);

Comment: Well, purpose of `Pattern.quote` is to create regex which will match our text literally. One of solutions could be changing quotation from entire string to single words and then join them with `\s*` between so we will get something like `quote(word1)\s*quote(word2)\s*quote(word3)`. Will update my answer with code example.